# Changing the position of the sign at the end of proofs

Tags: amsthm

In my thesis I'm using the following math related packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

I would like to change the position of the little square at the end of the proofs. More precisely I would like to make it appear right after the last word of the proof.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: if there's not enough space after the last word for the square, where do you want the square to appear?  at the left margin of the next line, or flush right on the next line?

Comment: In that case I would like to make it appear on the right on the next line. But actually it is not an urgent question anymore, because apparently my supervisor is happy with the standard position of the square in my thesis. ;)

Comment: Note that `amsthm` should be loaded *after* `mathtools` (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542849/125871)). Also, if you're loading `mathtools` there's no need to load `amsmath` since the former loads the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\addtotheoremprefoothook` from thmtools to typeset `\qedsymbol` then temporarily disable it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\addtotheoremprefoothook[proof]{%
  \qedsymbol%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem text
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof text.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: proof]