# How to right align QED at a specific line within align environment? [MWE]

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, packages

I have a proof which is concluded by a long, multi-line equation. I would like to place the QED right-aligned on the same line as the last line of the equation.

Without `\qedhere`, I get the desired right-aligned QED, except it's on a new line with undesired vertical space. I tried using `\hfill` but it didn't appear to do anything.

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}

\newtheorem {lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Proof includes a long, multi-line equation.
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  &= d. \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I right align the QED on the same line as the last line of the equation? Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is the order the packages are loaded. To get `\qedhere` to behave properly inside the `align*` environment, you need to load `amsmath` before `amsthm`.

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
```

[image]

Comment: That ordering requirement is documented in the `amsthm` user guide, but not for `amsmath`.  I've reported that and asked for an update (in due time).