# How to write the box symbol for end of proof on Overleaf

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, overleaf

I am using Overleaf to type up a paper involving proof of different results and I would like to write the box at the end of a proof that means QED ie end of proof. How can I do that? Thanks.

I am using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Do `\usepackage{amsthm}` and use `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` for the proofs. The QED symbol will magically appear.

Comment: @egreg thanks for that, it works brilliantly :)

Comment: Just make sure to load `amsmath` before `amsthm`. Otherwise the QED symbol can appear out of place in some environments. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542849/125871) for example.

Comment: @SandyG thanka a lot, your answer to that question is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @egreg said in the comments, you can use the `proof` environment from `amsthm`, which will automatically place a QED symbol at the end of the proof. You can also use the command `\qedsymbol`, also from `amsthm`, to place a QED symbol anywhere. Here's an example of both options, with the preamble you provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A proof written in the \verb|proof| environment. The QED symbol will appear at the end. 
\end{proof}

A \qedsymbol{} outside of a \verb|proof| environment. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, `amsthm` uses the command `\qedsymbol` to place the symbol at the end of the `proof` environment, so if you want to use something else as a QED symbol (for example a *black* square), you can simply redefine `\qedsymbol`, and the `proof` environment will use it.