# Is the amssymb package redundant?

Tags: amsmath, packages

Is it necessary to load the [`amssymb` package](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amssymb.pdf) when using the [`amsmath` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)? Stated another way, is `amssymb` redundant when one calls

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsxtra} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Alternatively, is it better to perform this as follows?

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsxtra} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Comment: `amssymb` provides additional symbols that aren't "named" in `amsfonts`; it is not redundant.  However, since you are loading `mathtools`, *that* loads `amsmath`, and you have made `amsmath` redundant.

Comment: @A.Ellett -- Here's what happens with these packages.  `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, but neither is loaded by `amsmath`.  `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and provides additions to that package.  All of `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `amsfonts` are "protected" against being loaded twice; I haven't checked `mathtools`, but it probably is too.  Still, it's not recommended to load *any* package twice.

Comment: Note that it *is* important to load `amsmath` before `amsthm` (or `mathtools`). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542849/125871).

Comment: I am using overleaf.  If amsmath is not loaded but mathtools is, the \qedhere command does not work in a gather* environment.

Comment: @Jar that comment does not really have anything to do with this question. `\qedhere` is not provided by `amsmath` nor `mathtools` it's defined in `amsthm` which needs to be loaded separately. Note that classes like `amsart` loads it automatically

Answer (score 6):

No, `amssymb` is not redundant with the other packages in your MWE.  It sets up [a number of other math fonts and symbols.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf)  Because its names for those fonts and symbols have become so standard, many other packages either load `amssymb` automatically, or provide their own version of the same symbols.

In contrast, `amsmath` sets up a large number of typesetting command, but does not change the fonts, `amsthm` sets up commands for theorems, and `amsxtra` sets up some rarely-used commands for backward compatibility.  Finally, `mathtools` extends `amsmath` with additional commands.

If you do not need `amssymb` because you are loading different math fonts, you do probably want to take it out.  The AMS fonts use up several of the sixteen math alphabets legacy 8-bit TeX allows you.  Trying to load more math alphabets than that could cause your document to fail, on some TeX engines.

Comment: Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32103/134641 and associated posts.