QED symbol in the last line of the formulas
\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma \ref{dual group of product several factors}]
We will induct on $n$. If $n=1$, then there is nothing to prove. Assume the result holds for $n\geq 1$ and let's prove for $n+1$. We have by Lemma 4:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(A_1\times \dots\times A_n\times A_{n+1})^{\widehat{}}&\cong (A_1\times \dots\times A_{n})^{\widehat{}}\times \widehat{A_{n+1}}\\
&\cong \widehat{A_1}\times \dots \times \widehat{A_{n}} \times \widehat{A_{n+1}}. \qedhere
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

If you compile this, the white box will appear right after the second line of the formula. I am wondering how to place it at the end of the line?
UPD. Here is the screenshot.


@CarLaTeX,I did that before posting. The white box appears immediately after the formula. I want it to be at the end of the line. I've added the screenshot. If you are confused, plese take a look.

Are you loading amsthm before amsmath? If so, switch them and use \qedhere. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542852/125871 You really need to post a MWE.

@SandyG The OP is using \qedhere but the symbol is not at their desired position

OT: I do not know what is messing up your space around the align, but maybe change ^{\widehat{}} into \sphat?

Don't use aligned inside equation*. Instead use align* and place \qedhere before \end{align*}.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma \ref{dual group of product several factors}]
We will induct on $n$. If $n=1$, then there is nothing to prove. Assume the result holds for $n\geq 1$ and let's prove for $n+1$. We have by Lemma 4:
\begin{align*}
(A_1\times \dots\times A_n\times A_{n+1})^{\widehat{}}&\cong (A_1\times \dots\times A_{n})^{\widehat{}}\times \widehat{A_{n+1}}\\
&\cong \widehat{A_1}\times \dots \times \widehat{A_{n}} \times \widehat{A_{n+1}}.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}


Thank you for your reply! What if I want to enumerate my equation?

If you want to enumerate all lines then the qed symbol has to move. Remove the * from align environment and delete \qedhere. If you don't want to enumerate the last line then just remove the *s.

Use \begin{aligned}[b] and qedhere after \end{aligned}.
By the way, I suggest a different strategy than \widehat{}, which sports bad spacing after it. Compare the two versions below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newcommand{\gwh}{\widehat{\hphantom{x}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma \ref{dual group of product several factors}]
We will induct on $n$. If $n=1$, then there is nothing to prove. Assume the 
result holds for $n\geq 1$ and let's prove for $n+1$. We have by Lemma~4:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
(A_1\times \dots\times A_n\times A_{n+1})^{\widehat{}}
  &\cong (A_1\times \dots\times A_{n})^{\widehat{}}\times \widehat{A_{n+1}}\\
  &\cong \widehat{A_1}\times \dots \times \widehat{A_{n}} \times \widehat{A_{n+1}}.
\end{aligned}\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma \ref{dual group of product several factors}]
We will induct on $n$. If $n=1$, then there is nothing to prove. Assume the 
result holds for $n\geq 1$ and let's prove for $n+1$. We have by Lemma~4:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[b]
(A_1\times \dots\times A_n\times A_{n+1})^{\gwh}
  &\cong (A_1\times \dots\times A_{n})^{\gwh}\times \widehat{A_{n+1}}\\
  &\cong \widehat{A_1}\times \dots \times \widehat{A_{n}} \times \widehat{A_{n+1}}.
\end{aligned}\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}


